# Android Compose WindowSizeClass Calculation Not Correct

Tags: android, kotlin, responsive-design, android-jetpack-compose

I have noticed something today and wanted to ask you about the cause of this.

I am trying to implement WindowSizeClass to build responsive layouts with Jetpack Compose. I have created a few AVDs. On of them is Pixel C tablet which has these dimensions in DP:
Portrait: 900 x 1200 - Landscape: 1280 x 820.

These dimensions comes from here:

```
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val widthInDp = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp
    val heightInDp = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "MerkeziSahne - widthInDp: $widthInDp")
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "MerkeziSahne - heightInDp: $heightInDp")
```

According to this page [Support different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes#window_size_classes) this device's window size classes should be like this:
For portrait:
Width: Expanded
Height: Expanded

For landscape:
Width: Expanded
Height: Medium

However, for landscape height size class returns **Expanded**. I am using below code to retrive window size classed:

```
                val windowSizeClass = calculateWindowSizeClass(this)
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, windowSizeClass.widthSizeClass.toString())
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, windowSizeClass.heightSizeClass.toString())
```

Why is there a difference? Is *calculateWindowSizeClass(this)* using all of the screen instead of available space or do I have a mistake somewhere?

I have checked the code for calculateWindowSizeClass(this).

```
@ExperimentalMaterial3WindowSizeClassApi
@Composable
fun calculateWindowSizeClass(activity: Activity): WindowSizeClass {
    // Observe view configuration changes and recalculate the size class on each change. We can't
    // use Activity#onConfigurationChanged as this will sometimes fail to be called on different
    // API levels, hence why this function needs to be @Composable so we can observe the
    // ComposeView's configuration changes.
    LocalConfiguration.current
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val metrics = WindowMetricsCalculator.getOrCreate().computeCurrentWindowMetrics(activity)
    val size = with(density) { metrics.bounds.toComposeRect().size.toDpSize() }
    return WindowSizeClass.calculateFromSize(size)
}
```

I guess it is not using *LocalConfiguration.current*, but I am not sure if this is the cause.

Comment: The portrait being 900 x 1200 and landscape being 1280 x 820 is a bit weird. Since in portrait it is 900dp width, maybe it is translated wrong when horizontal orientation is used, or something is preventing correct dimensions to be returned (e.g. status bar, navigation bar, display cut out etc...) Maybe check the screen and see if there are extra components?

Comment: AFAIK the dimensions reported are the dimensions of the **window** not the **screen**. That might be the cause.

Comment: Dimensions are different because of navigation bar I believe. However the problem is window size classes. They are not like they are explined in their web page. If their results change in the future that may break my application. Thanks for answering.